# how to get some div text on click in jquery..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, onclick, click

1. i want to 2nd div text on click li label
2. and also want 3rd div text on click li span

   Here Is My Structure structure ul > li > label > span > div > div > div

   ```
   $("#PlayListItem").on('click','label',function (){
        alert($("#PlayListItem li").find("div:nth-child(2)").text());
   });

   $("#PlayListItem").on('click','span',function (){
        alert($(this).find("div:nth-child(3)").text());
   });
   ```

Thanx In Advance.

Comment: Please include all relevant code.

Comment: Can the snippets please be tested before posted/approved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) pseudo-class selector wouldn't work since there is `span` as siblings, so use [`:nth-of-type()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) pseudo-class selector or jQuery [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) pseudo-class selector to get the element using index.

```
$("#PlayListItem").on('click','label',function (){
     alert($("#PlayListItem li").find("div:eq(1)").text());
});

$("#PlayListItem").on('click','span',function (){
     alert($('#PlayListItem li').find("div:eq(2)").text());
});
```

---

**UPDATE :** You can reduce the code by referring the element by the clicked element.

```
$("#PlayListItem").on('click','label',function (){
     alert($("div:eq(1)", this).text());
});

$("#PlayListItem").on('click','span',function (){
     alert($(this).parent().find("div:eq(2)").text());
});
```

Comment: Thanx For Response

Answer (score 0):

As your question is not clear but your can found a suggestion from here.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".readmore").click(function () {
        $(this).siblings(".pop").slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.pop {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a class="readmore">first div</a> 
        <div class="pop">this ts the text</div>
    </li>
    <li>
<a class="readmore">second div</a> 
        <div class="pop">this ts the text</div>
    </li>
    <li>
<a class="readmore">Third div</a> 
        <div class="pop">this ts the text</div>
    </li>
    <ul>
```